# Daily posts like an archive

Tags: posts, archives

I need to show 30 daily posts in the main page of a site. I also need to put 2 links, one that gets to a new page showing 30 posts made yesterday and the other to show 30 posts of 'tomorrow' if I'm looking at an older page.

I tried to use `wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'daily', 'limit' => 1 )`, but the thing is that now I have a page that shows a list of dates, and I need to click it to see the posts.

Is there a way form me to show the posts as soon as the visitor opens the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `wp_get_archives` as far as I know this will only output a list.

Instead use the WordPress loop and [WP Query's Date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) parameters.

For example to get yesterdays posts using `WP_Query` you can do something like:

```
$yesterday = date('d.m.Y',strtotime("yesterday"));
$yesterdayarray = date_parse($yesterday);

$query = new WP_Query( '&day=' . $yesterdayarray["day"] );
// grab the data in the loop
```

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, hope it works. I'll probably need some help. But thnx in advance ^^

Comment: I have to show 3 infos in every page. A link to the posts made 'yesterday' (from the day the user is viewing), a text with the day he is viewing, and a link to 'tomorrow's' posts.
That solution works for it? I tried some stuff here, but can't seem to get it.

Comment: Please read the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help, "do my work for me questions" are not allowed here, questions should be specific to a problem you face.

Comment: Hum, ok, but I only asked if that solution with 'wp_query' date filter is the right way to do the other stuff I said. Cuz I tried but it didn't worked, I don't know I i'm doing something wrong or if it's not suited for the function I need.
But thnx.

Comment: The query does work and it is the right way to query posts by date.